# Format Values displayed in ag-grid

Tags: angular, formatting, ag-grid

We are evaluating ag-grid to use in an anglular application which Displays Various of Reports as Tables.

We Need to Format values like Currencies (€), Decimal Values and DateTimes

How can we assign a Format to the Columns or implement a formating für the descibes cases. I found several Examples for DateTime but Nothing for decimals or Currencies.
Do i have to implement formating logic or is there a way to apply formating like 'dd.MM.yyyy' or 'c' or 'F02' like in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format can be done with pipes. The ag-grid probably don't include that. The format is better done directly on the value in the cells. 
Currency. Have a look at the currency pipe which is a built in feature in angular 2+
https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe